# Edit quantity in basket page and use update button to send data back using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Basically, I have an input field on the basket page where the users can update their quantity of items.

I would like to send this data back to the controller which has been set up.

My `HTML` is set up like so:

```
<li class="personalise-options__item">
@y.OptionName - <input name="playerdetails" maxlength="3" class="edit-me" value="@y.ValueName" contenteditable="@y.ValueName">
<span class="edit-icon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></span>
</li>
```

Below is my on click `ajax` call:

```
$(document).on('click', '.js-update-player', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('update player clicked');

    $.ajax({
        url: "/Basket/AjaxUpdatePlayerPersonalization",
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        data: { name: $('input[name="playerdetails"]').val() },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            if (data.Status == "Success") {
                alert("hello world");
            }
        }
    })
});
```

My issue is that I'm not getting an alert on success or a response in the network tab.

Any suggestions or advice on how to proceed would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: consider adding the server side code either.

Comment: `"nor a response in the network tab"` - i guess if you don't receive a response so you first inspect your backend. Btw, you better define onerror handlers for your $.ajax calls, friendly advice